# Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader' whilst trying to build an app in webpack

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, loader

So I am getting this error: `Error: Cannot resolve module 'json-loader'` when i run my `npm start` command.

I have tried to seek out solutions, one being changing my webpack.config.js from:

```
loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          loader: 'json-loader'
        },
```

to:

```
loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          exclude: '/node_modules',
          loader: 'json-loader'
        },
```

This only served to give me another error saying:

`/node_modules/mime-db/db.json Unexpected token (2:40)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

I have no idea how to fix this

Comment: It's `exclude: '/node_modules'`, with the apostrophes.

Comment: Have you run `npm install json-loader`?

Comment: @BenFortune yes but now that creates a new error saying proptotype is undefined in bundle

Answer (score 4):

You should include it in your package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
  }
```